# Восстановить коммиты в ветках

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

Исходный случай в репозитории:

```
master:     A
             \
develop:      X - Y - Z
```

Хотелось слить изменения (последний коммит) из `develop` в `master`:

```
master:     A - - - - - Z
             \         /
develop:      X - Y - Z
```

а получилось следующее:

```
master:    A - X - Y - Z
             \
develop:       X - Y - Z
```

Итак, **вопрос**: как вернуть репозиторию молодость и из третьего варианта сделать второй (или хотя бы первый)?

Comment: во втором варианте нужно было просто перенести коммит Z из develop  в master? Тогда почему после условного переноса на схеме он уже отмечен как B?

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko да. Поправил, спасибо

Comment: @Oleg, всё было правильно. Потому что мердж-коммит - это другой коммит.

Comment: Может таки получилось `master, develop:    A - X - Y - Z`?

Comment: @vp_arth, это если мердж. А если он переносит с помощью cherry-pick, то коммит в случае отсутствия конфликтов останется тем же

Comment: @Oleg, почти тем же. У него будет другой хеш.

Comment: @vp_arth, согласен, упустил это в контексте вопроса

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете смысл мержа. Он не последний коммит переносит, а соединяет ветки.

Comment: Если вы ещё заходите сюда, могу объяснить в ответе подробно. :)

Comment: Честно говоря, уже поздно. Но спасибо

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko другой хеш — значит другой коммит. Да и зачем ему тут cherry-pick? Достаточно объединить и замержить, лучше если с `--no-ff`.

Answer (score 4):

на самом деле Вы получили следующее у Вас произошел fast-forward. B и показать это в Ваших обозначениях сложно.

Что делать? либо не переживать - оно уже правильно (там нет двух веток. Там одна.)

Либо сделать так, как Вы хотите

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard A
git merge --no-ff develop
```

параметр `--no-ff` делает ровно то, что Вы хотите. Остальные две команды нужны только для того, что бы привести состояние репозитория к первому состоянию.

Comment: Команды выполнил, но ситуация осталась прежней. Задумывалось сбросить только готовый вариант из develop в master, а сбросились все коммиты

Comment: то есть, наблюдается третий вариант?

Comment: так точно, всё по-прежнему

Comment: есть подозрение, что Вы неверно трактуете наблюдаемые изменения. Показывайте вывод `git log --graph --oneline --all` - будет понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял

перейти на мастер

> git checkout master

сброcить мастер до A

> git reset --hard %sha_A%

перенести Z из develop в master

> git cherry-pick %sha_Z%